# Magento trying to create CSV inside a directory throwing FATAL error Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento, csv

I have a script that creates a file and currently puts it inside media folder, but I'd like to have it inside media/files so here is my code

$filePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'files'. 'mycsvfile.csv';

$fileName = 'mycsvfile.csv';

```
        $mageCsv = new Varien_File_Csv();
        $mageCsv->saveData($filePath, $ordersRow);  
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()
                   ->getResponse()
                   ->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('mycsvfiles/adminhtml_download/index/', array('file' => $fileName )));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors in your code - aside from

```
$filePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'files'. 'mycsvfile.csv';
```

should probably be

```
$filePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'files'. DS . 'mycsvfile.csv';
```

since *files* is a directory. The error you see is probably thrown somewhere else. Try to check your etc section .xml files - the directives **translate**="label" **module**="*modulename*" where *modulename* is a helper alias. I've had a couple of such errors the other day.